# select Tab Bar button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to hide an image when the tabBar button is pressed.I have

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

in my app delegate and the code below is located in my view controller's .m file . but it doesn't work . Can anyone help pls ?

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if (viewController.tabBarController  == nil)
    {
       img.hidden = YES;
       NSLog(@"Tab Bar Button");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this method and check whether this method is getting there..Also where you are creating img?

Comment: Check console to see if Tab bar button is printed.

Comment: i've checked and it's not printed

Comment: img is also created in the same .m file

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that

> In versions of iOS prior to version
>   3.0, this method is called only when the selected view controller actually
>   changes. In other words, it is not
>   called when the same view controller
>   is selected.

In addition to this, make sure you are hiding the `imageView` that contains the image.

**UPDATE**

Get the `tabBarController` instance in the view controller and make its delegate the view controller. Then you can call this method in the view controller.

Comment: i have a button which hides the imageView so i'm sure that it's hidden

Comment: i did your update but the application didn't start with that and console says 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907857/changing-the-delegate-of-a-tab-bar-exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108782/tab-bar-controller-raising-nsinternalinconsistencyexception

Answer (score 0):

give name for the tabbarcontroller and then set the delegate for that.If my suggestion not useful,then ask me freely

Comment: i changed it's name and gave delegation but the application didn't start with that and console says 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Comment: Did u get any warnings?  and is this delegate method calling?

Comment: did you created the tabbarcontroller programmatically or in xib

Comment: all in xib and in appdelegate file but not in a view controller but i imported the appdelegate to it

Comment: you need to paste the delegate method in appdelegate but not in your viewcontroller

Comment: it,s always been in appdelegate .. the only method exists in viewcontroller is - (void) tabBarController method